# populating second drop down box from contents of first

Tags: php

I finally got my first dropdown box populating from my database, but now the second dropdown box isn't even appearing, I think something's messed up with my if statement calling the second function, but not sure what also not sure if my "WHERE" statement is correct in my query Here's my code

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Department</td>";
echo "<td><div id=\"deptdiv\"><select name=\"department\">";
echo "<option>Select Department</option>";
echo "</td>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<option value="'.$row['abbrev'].'">'.$row['abbrev'].'</option>';
}

if($_GET[department] == "department" && isset($_GET[department])) {
drop_2($_GET[department]);
}
function drop_2($id)
{
$query = mysql_query("SELECT courseno, name FROM course WHERE department=$id");

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Course</td>";
echo "<td><div id \"coursediv\"><select name=\"course\">";
echo "<option>Select Course</option>";
echo "</td>";
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo '<option value="'.$r['courseno'].'">'.$r['name'].'</option>';
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised the first dropdown shows since you have table tags within the `<select>` element, and never closed that tag. I think that is the main problem. Try like:

```
echo "<td><div id=\"deptdiv\"><select name=\"department\">";
echo "<option>Select Department</option>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo '<option value="'.$row['abbrev'].'">'.$row['abbrev'].'</option>';
}
echo "</select></div></td>";
```

Also you need to put quotes around the GET variables so that PHP doesn't think they are constants do like `$_GET['department']` and close the select tag at the end of the drop_2 function. Also in the function move the `</td>` tag to after closing the select.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Do the quotes in the $_GET have to be escaped?

Comment: the $_GET quotes only need escaping if you use the same type of quote within a string encapsulated by that type. So "This $_GET[\"this\"] needs to be escaped" but "this $_GET['this'] doesn't" For even mor fun check out the heredoc syntax http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php and =use even fewer quotes but it adds, sometimes a bunch of {} so maybe walk before running.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your corrected code..

```
 echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Department</td>";
echo "<td><div id=\"deptdiv\"><select name=\"department\">";
echo "<option>Select Department</option>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<option value="'.$row['abbrev'].'">'.$row['abbrev'].'</option>';
}
echo "</div>";
echo "</td></tr>";
if($_GET['department'] == "department" && isset($_GET['department'])) {
drop_2($_GET['department']);
}
function drop_2($id)
{
$query = mysql_query("SELECT courseno, name FROM course WHERE department=$id");

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Course</td>";
echo "<td><div id \"coursediv\"><select name=\"course\">";
echo "<option>Select Course</option>";
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo '<option value="'.$r['courseno'].'">'.$r['name'].'</option>';
}
echo "</div>";
echo "</td></tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I think the problem is with my if statement because I put an echo inside of it, and it's not printing out, I'm not sure if the entire if statement is right